# Kotlin M11: Suppress "Function is never used" in IntelliJ 14.1

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio 1.2 Preview which is based on IntelliJ 14.1 EAP and recently updated to Kotlin M11. For a certain method, the IDE reports that it is unused. I was used to having an intention that says "Suppress warning for element/method/class" but it seems to be gone now.

How can I suppress the warning, at least manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Preferences → Editor → Inspections → Kotlin → Unused Symbol (faster is to search "unused symbol" in Preferences search bar). There you can configure annotations to suppress this warning (this setting is shared among analogous inspections for Java)

For Kotlin, warning suppression now works only for compiler diagnostics
, not for IDE-only inspections. I have filed an issue for it: [KT-7060](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7060)